# scrypt key calculator

Tags: shell, software-rec, utilities, cryptography

`scrypt` is a password-based key derivation function that can be tuned to use a large amount of memory.

I want a command-line interface to calculate the key given my own values for parameters: `password`, `salt`, `n`, `r`, `p`, `length` (these are like the parameters `password`, `salt`, `cost` in `bcrypt`).

Preferably, I can use something like `scrypt --password message --salt mysalt -n 1024 -r 8 -p 8 --length 32` and get just `9a5ef931679f5003248953b6eea3827ca32eb6d07a417126670ba8555f40a0e0`.

What software can do this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation of `scrypt` appears to cover your requirement, see https://github.com/jkalbhenn/scrypt

```
scrypt-kdf [options ...] password [salt N r p size salt-size]
                         string string integer integer integer integer integer]
options
  -b|--base91-input  password and salt arguments are base91 encoded
  -c|--check hash  test if hash is derived from a password
  -h|--help  display this text and exit
  -p|--crypt  use unix crypt format
  -v|--version  output version information and exit
```